# Python mockito tuples

Tags: python, tuples, mockito

I am trying to mock a method that returns a tuple in the below form

(List(List),List(List))

```
class MockTuples(object):
def methodReturnsComplexTuple(some dummy arguments):
  return ([['I am a list at index 1']],[['I am a list at index 2']])
```

Below is the mockito class

```
from mockito import mock, when, verify, any, verifyNoMoreInteractions,unstub
import unittest
#Other imports as required

class testMockTuples(unittest.TestCase):
 def setup():
 def tearDown():
 def mockMethodReturnsComplexTuple():
   mocked_class = mock(MockTuples())
   when(mocked_class).methodReturnsComplexTuple(arguments).thenReturn(Place the tuple here)
```

At this point - I am getting the below error

```
if Ellipsis in args:
```

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

How do I approach the mocking for the complex tuple?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem. Trying to get cognito to returna a tuble.

Comment: Sorry. In the above comment it says "cognito", should have said 'Mockito'